# Beef sausage in pork casing, can I remove it?

Tags: halal-haram

I recently bought some beef sausages a few days ago and didn't realize that they were in a pork casing. Is it permissible to cut open the casing and simply use the beef?

Comment: I'm confused. Pork casing as in the casing they use to fill ground pork in for pork sausages?

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile The collagen casing they fill with the sausage is made from pork, but all the sausage itself is beef. I'm asking if it's fine to cut open the casing and just eat the meat inside.

Comment: in that case no. Muslims are told to stay away from anything pork-related, even if there's a way around to ignore it. The meat may still be contaminated with pork. May I ask, are you buying halal meat? Because if so, then there should be no worry about pork being involved.